# Why is the 2-bond (Sn-H) coupling constant larger than the 3-bond Sn-H coupling constant for tetraethyltin?

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy, organometallic-compounds

I was looking at the NMR spectrum of tetraethyltin [$\ce{Sn(CH2CH3)4}$], and found that the $\ce{Sn-H}$ coupling constant between $\ce{Sn}$ and $\ce{CH2}$ is larger than that between $\ce{Sn}$ and $\ce{CH3}$.

$\hspace{4.1cm}$[image: SnEt4]

$$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline {}^2J({}^{119}\ce{Sn-H}) & {}^3J({}^{119}\ce{Sn-H}) \\ \hline \pu{49.2 Hz} & \pu{68.6Hz} \\ \hline  \end{array}$$

This trend is confirmed by literature values[1].

However, I am confused as to why this is happening. The magnitude of the coupling constant is determined by the Fermi contact mechanism, so surely the **coupling constant over two bonds should be larger than the coupling constant over 3 bonds?** The ethyl groups also should have free rotation, so any type of **angle effects should be cancelled out on average**.

So why is ${}^2J$ smaller than ${}^3J$ here?

---

Reference:

1. G. Barbieri, F. Taddei, "117Sn, 119Sn–proton long-range coupling constants in the 1H nuclear magnetic resonance spectra of alkylhalogenostannanes", *J. Chem. Soc.*, *Perkin Trans. 2*, 1972, **10**, 1327

Comment: Presumably it’s not just Fermi contact interactions. Note that 2J and 3J of 13C-1H have the same pattern - there’s a paper on this which I will try to find...

Comment: @orthocresol Thank you. So, are there other mechanisms except Fermi contact for nuclear spin coupling? I was only aware of Fermi contact. And please mention the paper if you find it, that would be very helpful.

Comment: This is quite a broad area and one that I'm not qualified to discuss myself, but here are a few relevant papers: https://doi.org/10.1021/jp0353284 (talks about C–H), https://doi.org/10.1021/jo200513q (talks about H–H where Fermi contact is the most important factor, but also summarises some of the other factors), https://doi.org/10.1002/chem.200306065 (discusses factors), https://doi.org/10.1021/ed084p156 (maybe the most accessible)